# How to make Material-UI Radio buttons float: left

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, material-ui, styling

https://codesandbox.io/s/9zxzj0r664

[image]

^ In the demo above you can see the working code, anyways having a hard time just trying to align the radio buttons horizontally.

Is there an easy way to do this in Material-UI? Or do I have to style my own Radio buttons, which I could have done in 5 minutes lol.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  formControl: {
    float: "left",
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  },
  group: {
    margin: `${theme.spacing.unit}px 0`
  }
});

class RadioButtonsGroup extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "female"
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <FormControl
          component="fieldset"
          required
          className={classes.formControl}
        >
          <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup
            aria-label="gender"
            name="gender1"
            className={classes.group}
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              value="female"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="Female"
            />
            <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
            <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="disabled"
              disabled
              control={<Radio />}
              label="(Disabled option)"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl
          component="fieldset"
          required
          error
          className={classes.formControl}
        >
          <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup
            aria-label="gender"
            name="gender2"
            className={classes.group}
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              value="male"
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label="Male"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="female"
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label="Female"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="other"
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label="Other"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              value="disabled"
              disabled
              control={<Radio />}
              label="(Disabled option)"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
          <FormHelperText>You can display an error</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

RadioButtonsGroup.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(RadioButtonsGroup);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/n03mo5nz2m

The `RadioGroup` elements contain the radio buttons. If you'd like to render them in a row, the easiest way is probably to use a flexbox row.

You can see what I've done in the above codesandbox, but it's as simple as adding to the `group` style:

```
flexDirection: 'row',
```

This works because Material-UI already uses flexbox styling for the group. That's also the reason it doesn't work to add `float: 'left'` there.

You could also set `display: 'inline-block'` on the group:

```
display: 'inline-block'
```

And that'll also achieve row styling, but with fewer control options.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that has one "native" way to do this in material UI, you have to do this on you own. it's a better aproach in fact.

Comment: Just found a way, posting now

Comment: on material UI?

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/yp84vnzpq1

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";

const styles = theme => ({
  formControl: {
    display: "flex",
    float: "left",
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  },
  group: {
    float: "left",
    flexDirection: "row",
    margin: `${theme.spacing.unit}px 0`
  }
});

class RadioButtonsGroup extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "male 1"
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <RadioGroup
          aria-label="gender"
          name="gender1"
          className={classes.group}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <FormControlLabel value="male 1" control={<Radio />} label="Male 1" />
          <FormControlLabel value="male 2" control={<Radio />} label="Male 2" />
          <FormControlLabel value="male 3" control={<Radio />} label="Male 3" />
        </RadioGroup>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

RadioButtonsGroup.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(RadioButtonsGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can Change the props of radio group as row/column with new MUI v5

```
       <RadioGroup
          row
          aria-labelledby="mstatus" defaultValue="Single" value={value}
          onChange={handleMaritalChange} name=...../>
```